# Square root of a function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $D$ be  a circular annulus in $\Bbb C$ with center at $0$. Put $v(z)=z$, for every $z\in D$. Show that $v$ has no square root measurable function.

I think if define function $h$ such that $h(re^{i \theta}) = r^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}$ we have a square root for $v$, but is $h$ measurable? or is my result correct?

Comment: Can't remember the precise definition of a measurable function, but I'd guess that the large distance between $h(-1 + \epsilon i)$ and $(-1 - \epsilon i)$ is a factor.

Comment: Or alternative splitting point depending how you uniquely choose $\theta$.

Comment: @lanF1 : So you mean there is not any square root?

Comment: Given that the question says "show that there is not", I'd guess there is not :) As I say I'm a bit rusty, I hope my above comment doesn't turn out to lead you wrong. Someone with more recent knowledge will hopefully post an answer soon.

Comment: Your definition of $h$ is not well defined. What does it give as the value of $h(e^{i\pi})$? as the value of $h(e^{i\cdot3\pi})$? Those values aren't compatible with each other.

Comment: @GregMartin: Yes, I can not define $h$ such above. Please give me the exact reason of that $v$ has not root.

Answer (score 1):

There is a measurable square root function on an annulus, and the one you have written down works. (With some extra care.)

If $\Omega = \{ z : a < |z| < b \}$ and $z = \Omega$, we can find unique $r \in (a,b)$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, such that $z = re^{i\theta}$. Put $h(z) = \sqrt{r}\,e^{i\theta/2}$ to get your measurable square root.

On the other hand, it's impossible to find a *holomorphic* or even *continuous* square root on $\Omega$. For the continuous case, just look at the circle $|z| = \rho$ for some $a < \rho < b$. By the above, any square root $h$ must be of the form
$$ h(\rho e^{i\theta}) = \sqrt{\rho} e^{i(\theta+n(\theta))/2} $$
where $n(\theta) \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ for every $\theta$. If $n$ is not constant on $[0,2\pi)$, clearly $h$ is not continuous (the sign of $h$ flips when we change $n$). If $n$ is constant, then we have a discontinuty at $z = \rho = \rho e^{0i} = \rho e^{2\pi i}$. In either case, we get our contradiction.